# Compare the condition from the data retrieve from Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I would like to set the condition to verify the userType in the firestore in everytime I login into the app.

For example:

**if the userType is Customer I would like go the CustomerMainScree**n ;

**if the userType is Confinement Lady I would like go the CLLadyMainScreen**;

Here is my Firestore image:
[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIXta.png)

Below is my code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, userSnapshot) {
          // if (userSnapshot.hasData && userSnapshot.data['userType']== 'Confinement Lady') {
          //   return CLLadyMainScreen();
          // }
          // if (userSnapshot.hasData && userSnapshot.data['userType']== 'Customer') {
          //   return CustomerMainScreen();
          // }
          if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
            if (userSnapshot.data()['userType'] == 'Confinement Lady') {
              return CLLadyMainScreen();
            } else if (userSnapshot.data()['userType'] == 'Customer') {
              return CustomerMainScreen();
            }
          }
          return AuthScreen();
        });
  }
```

But this error pop out when I click the sign in button :
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfUQQ.png)

How should I fix this?

The problem exist now:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvmnk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need another Streambuilder to access the documents in Firestore, and pass it another stream to the current user's information. I'm also assuming that every user document in the collection is the user's UID:

```
if(userSnapshot.hasData) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
      // snapshot returns user doc.

        if(snapshot.data == null) {
           return Container(); // Return some kind of spinner or loading widget so firebase can retrieve the data and you don't get an error
        }

        if (snapshot.data['userType'] == 'Confinement Lady') {
              return CLLadyMainScreen();
        } else {
              return CustomerMainScreen();
        }
    }
} else {
   return AuthScreen();
}
```

Comment: But the in the builder part, there is an error indicate is has a missing return. 
This is the error message -->
This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

Comment: You could setup a boolean variable above the for loop and based on the result of the if statement sequence, you can change the variable to true or false, then made another if statement sequence based on that boolean and return the screen accordingly. I think you're getting an error because the return statement is inside a for loop. I'll edit answer if all goes well. (Also remember to keep that return AuthScreen() statement there too!)

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what are you trying to said. Can you write a example.

Comment: I believe I messed something up in my example and my code sample from before, this edited version should work.

Comment: it still return the same error as before. I post the screenshot of the code at the question

Comment: I forgot to add the return keyword to the second streambuilder which I believe is why you're getting the blue squiggly lines. I edited the answer.

Comment: it is just remove some partition of that blue squiggly lines. Other part still remain the same.
You can check it at the Problem exist message, I had updated the Problem exist.

Comment: It still appear the blue squiggly line. But it solved anyway. It can be directed to the page I want. So I guess the blue line is not a big problem.

Comment: It sort've is a problem, that you may not notice now but potentially could be in the future. I edited the code so that I believe it shouldn't be there any more.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. The blue thing gone. Appreciate it. :)